# What does "Slash the life" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does the expression "Slash the life" mean? I'm Brazilian and I'm trying to understand what is the meaning of this expression, since I've found it in a  music piece that seems to have a positive meaning. But "slash" in Portuguese is a verb that can be used mainly for physical things (e.g.: slash an apple, slash a piece of cake etc.) or for abstract things in negative meanings (e.g.: slash the dream, slash the happiness etc.).

Comment: What song did you find it in?  Can you provide the context in which it's used?

Comment: Link to English lyrics?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to [this song](http://letras.mus.br/digimon/519674/) from Digimon. Japanese anime songs are known for being peppered with English phrases which are often artificial, i.e. phrases we don't use. This is one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is an action that triggers an immediate change in someone, perhaps they are referring to the digimons here, since it continues in one of the sentences with "Wild instinct awakens. Wild one! A hidden energy" translated from Japanese. The action appears to be "Card slash". I have found in translations that refer to "Slash the life" as releasing or awakening an inner force.

But it can also have another interpretation that I found in this article. 'Slash life' trend allows workers to chase their dreams: https://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/202302/08/WS63e2ee2fa31057c47ebad810.html

And it could make sense in the lives of the protagonists who feel that they have a life in the real world but also in the digital world but their parents did not accept it and "Slash the life" would mean cut life in 2, you can do both.